# Cross platform path swapping

Tags: python

I am using python to do some cross platform path swapping.

```
import platform 

def filenameFix(filename):
    if platform.system() in ("Windows", "Microsoft"):
        return filename.replace ( "/Volumes/projects/", "p:/")
    else:
        return filename.replace( "p:/", "/Volumes/projects/" )
    return filename
```

This works fine to swap the paths for `/Volumes/projects/`, however I want it to also swap paths for `Volumes/projects` in the first if block. The only difference is the forward slash before `Volumes` has been removed... How could I do this?

Comment: How is this question unclear? It's perfectly clear. The title is misleading though.

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence can you show us what happens

Comment: I think he wants /Volumes/projects removed if in there, but Volumes/projects removed without the slash if that's in there

Answer (score 2):

Windows supports forward slashes in paths, and so does linux. So you can just use `/` in all locations, which also helps remove problems with escaping using the `\` character.

If that is not working for you, or you are also running on other systems, or systems that work differently (like mac maybe). Then you can use `os.path.join()`

Or you could use this:

```
import sys

def get_path(filename):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        return filename.replace("/Volumes/projects/", "p:/")
    else:
        return filename.replace("p:/", "/Volumes/projects/")
```

Best practice would be to not hard-code the "root" element of the path, and instead obtain it relatively by using `os.getenv('HOME')` or some such constant, or by getting relative path of the script being run, and building the directory tree from that, using:

```
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is much better to you than you think, if you just let it :)

```
import os.path

def get_dir():
    return "p:/" if platform.system() in ("Windows", "Microsoft") else "..."

def full_filename(filename):
    return os.path.join(get_dir(), filename)
```

Comment: But a little off-topic because the OP wants a `filenameFix()` function, so input is a filename which already contains the directory.

Comment: True, I made some assumptions about the surroundings of this code that are probably wrong (basically, my points was, instead of building that string, use such a function to create a proper filename in the first place, but that doesn't work if the filenames come from elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a replace without the leading `/`, and then remove any leading `/` that might exist.

```
import platform 

def filenameFix(filename):
    if platform.system() in ("Windows", "Microsoft"):
        return filename.replace( "Volumes/projects/", "p:/").lstrip('/')
    else:
        return filename.replace( "p:/", "/Volumes/projects/" )
    return filename

>>> s1
'/Volumes/projects/blah/'
>>> s2
'Volumes/projects/blah/'
>>> s1.replace('Volumes/projects/', 'p:/').lstrip('/')
'p:/blah/'
>>> s2.replace('Volumes/projects/', 'p:/').lstrip('/')
'p:/blah/'
```

Comment: thanks for all the replies. :-) one other issue i am experiencing is, when it translates the path... i get a leading forward slash eg /p:/, which is causing issues as it can not resolve the path. this only happens with /volumes/projects.

Comment: @ash Yeah I'm an idiot.. I forgot the extra slash would be at the start of the string, not after the `p:/`. All fixed now.

Comment: @ash see the solution now using .lstrip('/')

Comment: @ash It shouldn't. Look at the examples I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this actually answers your question better than my initial answer... if the first replace fails, look for the same pattern but without the slashes.

```
def filenameFix(filename):
    if platform.system() in ("Windows", "Microsoft"):
        return filename.replace ( "/Volumes/projects/", "p:/").replace("Volumes/projects/", "p:/")
    else:
        return filename.replace( "p:/", "/Volumes/projects/" )
    return filename
```

Comment: I guess this is calling for a RegEx ;)

Comment: thanks....this works, and it replaces filenames for both /Volumes/projects and Volumes/projects. however when replacing for /volumes/projects it inserts a forward slash before p:/. any ideas?

Comment: odd. sounds like the behaviour that would be expected if you swapped the two chained replace commands (because it'd take the Volumes/.../ and leave the initial /) - any chance they're swapped?

Comment: nope, not swapped, it swaps the path correctly for Volumes/projects to p:/, but for /Volumes/projects it swaps to /p:/ .